# Как получить имя авторизованного пользователя VK на своем сайте?

Tags: php, javascript, vkontakte-api

Интересует вопрос, как можно получить имя пользователя, который зашел на мой сайт, если он авторизован в ВК.

Не прибегая авторизации через "Мои приложения".

Comment: А как сайт узнает, что он в ВК? И как это вам, без подтверждения, ВК разрешит, что - то смотреть?

Comment: Никак. Где имя, там и пароли, явки, секретная переписка - всё конфедициальная информация. Если Вы не ФСБ (ВК - не телеграм) или не получили разрешения от пользователя - только хаки и недосмотр. Они есть, но незаконны, да и нестабильны (сегодня есть, а завтра обнаружат и прикроют).

Comment: @Vlad, Вообще раньше можно было чарез апи с небольшим хаком. Сейчас не в курсе. Но учить вас этому я не буду, и думаю здесь никто не будет.

Comment: Ключевой вопрос - зачем?

Answer (score 0):

Легально -- никак, это против правил сайта сайта, да и в целом неэтично.